# Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions on using GoogleApiClient in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api, google-api-client

I am trying to use Place Autocomplete API in my app. I have a main `Activity`. I have a `Fragment` which is a part of `MainActivity`. In `OnViewCreated()` on this `Fragment`.

```
 private void rebuildGoogleApiClient() {
    // When we build the GoogleApiClient we specify where connected and connection failed
    // callbacks should be returned and which Google APIs our app uses.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(activity, 0 /* clientId */, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();
}
```

StackTrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1471)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:488)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzl.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zzkL(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
        at com.app.projectpapri.Fragments.LocationScreen.rebuildGoogleApiClient(LocationScreen.java:69)
        at com.app.projectpapri.Fragments.LocationScreen.onViewCreated(LocationScreen.java:93)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:971)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
        at com.app.projectpapri.core.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1243)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of calling `rebuildGoogleApiClient()` in `onViewCreated()`, try calling it in your fragment's `onActivityCreated()` method.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle for more information on the fragment lifecycle.

If that still doesn't work, you could remove `enableAutoManage(...)` and call `connect()` and `disconnect()` explicitly on the `GoogleApiClient` instance.

See https://developers.google.com/places/android/start#connect-client for details.

Does that help?

Comment: Removing `enableAutoManage(...)` and using `connect()` worked for me. Although not sure why. Accepting your answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
public class TestActivity extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
}
```